# A Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Finding the number of $(a, b, c)$, where $a, b, c$ are positive
>   integers, that
>
> $$
> \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{ab}+\frac{c^2+b^2-a^2}{cb}+\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{ac}=2+\frac{15}{abc} 
> $$

---

I factored it in the following form
$(a+b+c)(2ab+2ac+2bc-a^2-b^2-c^2)=8abc+15$. But I can't make any progress from here.

Also I tried working with case when $a, b, c$ are sides of a triangle to get,
$\cos A+\cos C+\cos B=1+\frac{15}{2abc} < \frac{3}{2}$.
But that gives a lower bound on $abc$ which is not very helpful either.

Comment: $2+\frac {15}{2abc}\lt \frac 32$ can't happen with positive $a,b,c$...

Comment: @abiessu Do you mean assuming the equation? [ Otherwise for large $a,b,c$ it could be just slightly above $2.$ ]

Comment: sorry, it will be $\frac{15}{abc}+2< 3$

Comment: Mos -- If the desired solutions should also have the right side less than 3, it would be good to insert that constraint into the question itself, not just mention it in a comment.

Comment: @coffemath, no the question doesn't provide us with that bound on the solutions. We get $\frac{15}{2abc}+1 < \frac{3}{2}$ because in a triangle $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C < \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Mos -- does the problem say that a,b,c are sides of a triangle? I ask because the terms in the left of the inequality (apart from a missing factor of 2 in the denominators) look like what the law of cosines gives, but in the stated question it wasn't assumed a,b,c were triangle sides...

Comment: @coffeemath, it wasn't given in the question that $a, b, c$ are sides of a triangle. That's why wrote 'i tried working with case when a, b, c are sides of a triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

$$\Longleftrightarrow c(a^2+b^2-c^2)+a(b^2+c^2-a^2)+b(a^2+c^2-b^2)-2abc=15$$
and note that
$$c(a^2+b^2-c^2)+a(b^2+c^2-a^2)+b(a^2+c^2-b^2)-2abc=(c-a+b)(a-b+a)(c-a-b)$$
so
$$(c-a+b)(c-b+a)(c-a-b)=15=1\cdot 3\cdot 5$$